# 1st Row of ListView Height

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapterview

I am trying to make the height of the first row of my listView taller than the remaining.  I am able to a apply a different layout for row 1, but I cannot make the height different.  I am using a custom adapter...here is my getView that chooses the appropriate row layout:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    int theType = getItemViewType(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (theType == 0) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.location_list_row_one, null);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            imagView.setBackground(R.drawable.image);
            TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            name.setText("Name");

        } else if (theType == 1) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.location_list_row_two, null);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            imagView.setBackground(R.drawable.image);
            TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            name.setText("Name");
        }
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

My row layouts are wrapped in a Relative layout, so I need to make the RL height taller in row one.  Any ideas?

Comment: What height is using in root Layout in `location_list_row_one` xml?

Comment: So do you want a padding of sorts for your listView?Why cannot you give  a topPadding or margin for your list view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `padding`:

```
convertView.setPadding(left, right, top, bottom);
```

Comment: I tried layoutParams...and many other trials and errors.  I missed the obvious...thanks!  I actually ended up setting the padding in my xml for row 1 and that worked too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different layout and add as headerview to listview.